# DateDiff with WHERE clause NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im trying to get the time difference between two values in a table and eliminate all NULLs.

```
SELECT NumberOfMinutes =
   DATEDIFF(millisecond, tbl_hugo_game.time_start, tbl_hugo_game.time_end)
FROM tbl_hugo_game 
WHERE numberofminutes <> NULL 
ORDER BY numberofminutes ASC
```

without the `WHERE`-clause it is working fine, 
otherwise :

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'numberofminutes'.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use column aliases in a `where` clause.

You can, however, put the query with the alias as a source for another query, like this:

```
select * from (
  select DATEDIFF(...) AS NumberOfMinutes 
  FROM tbl_hugo_game) source
where NumberOfMinutes is not null 
order by NumberOfMinutes asc
```

Comment: You'll want to use `NumberOfMinutes IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, tnx, copy/paste got the better or me :)

Answer (score 0):

The logical processing order of this SELECT statement is

a) `FROM tbl_hugo_game`

b) `WHERE numberofminutes <> NULL`

c)

```
SELECT
DATEDIFF(millisecond ,tbl_hugo_game.time_start,tbl_hugo_game.time_end) AS NumberOfMinutes
```

d) `ORDER BY numberofminutes ASC`

Thus, the step c) (the SELECT clause with DATEDIFF ... AS NumberOfMinutes computed field) is processed after step b) (the WHERE clause) and before step d) (the ORDER BY clause). This is the reason why the computed field from step c) (DATEDIFF ... AS NumberOfMinutes) can't be used in WHERE clause (step b) but can be used in the ORDER BY clause (step d).

References: [SELECT (Transact-SQL) # Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

> The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding
>   order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects
>   defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent
>   steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the
>   tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their
>   columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely,
>   because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived
>   columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding
>   clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as
>   the ORDER BY clause. Note that the actual physical execution of the
>   statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary
>   from this list.
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

Answer (score 0):

Where Clause can't access column aliases.
It's better and simpler for your case to rewrite the query (without using of subselect) simply as:

```
SELECT NumberOfMinutes =
DATEDIFF(millisecond, tbl_hugo_game.time_start, tbl_hugo_game.time_end)
FROM tbl_hugo_game 
WHERE tbl_hugo_game.time_start  IS NOT NULL AND tbl_hugo_game.time_end IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY numberofminutes ASC
```